# Should I protect ajax-only controllers from full requests?

Tags: ajax, json, design-patterns

I have some controllers which return JSON and are designed to be hit by XHR requests only.  Should I trap and redirect non-XHR requests?

This is a question about style and presentation, more than technology.

Answer (score 2):

> Should I trap and redirect non-XHR requests?

You can't be 100% certain that a non-XHR request really is one. The most common way of telling the difference is through the non-standard `x-requested-with` header, which can easily be spoofed/set by any HTTP client, so really, I wouldn't bother, unless it is useful to differentiate request types in the context of your specific application.